# What a hubbub of [pubsub]! (Rename [pubsubhubbub] to [websub])

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Currently,

- [pubsubhubbub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pubsubhubbub)
- [pubsub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pubsub) → [publish-subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/publish-subscribe)

PubSub is a short name for PubSubHubBub, which has now been renamed to WebSub. So we should have this:

- [pubsub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pubsub) → [pubsubhubbub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pubsubhubbub) → [websub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/websub)

Meanwhile, Publish Subscribe might be used to describe this specific protocol, but according to the tag wiki it's more about the *pattern* in general. So that should perhaps be a separate tag.

- [publish-subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/publish-subscribe)

Comment: Upvoted without really checking to see if this is even appropriate.

Comment: Try saying that 10 times.

Comment: How do people even come up with these names?

Comment: Reading that tag name makes my think of GrubHub.

Comment: Iä! Iä! Pub-Subburath! The Black Protocol of the Webs with a Thousand Consumers!

Comment: "*PubSub is a short name for PubSubHubBub*" - or an abbreviation of publish-subscribe (the pattern). The current synonym is fine.

Comment: I know naming things is hard, but this is ridiculous.

Comment: This sounds like when you push out whipped cream from a half-empty can.

Comment: Wait: PubSubWebHub or PubSubWebHubBub? I'm confused.

Comment: [Only one man should be allowed to use "bub".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolverine_(character))

Answer (score 24):

> PubSub is a short name for PubSubHubBub

What? No! PubSub is a design pattern which PubSubHubbub/WebSub *uses*, but they are not synonyms. [WebSub](https://w3c.github.io/websub/#abstract) is a specification for implementing PubSub over HTTP, but PubSub needn't involve HTTP at all; for instance, I've used the PubSub feature provided [by Redis](https://redis.io/topics/pubsub) and [read that it's also offered by Postgres](https://pgdash.io/blog/postgres-features.html).

As such, the [pubsub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pubsub) -> [pubsubhubbub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pubsubhubbub) synonym you're asking for would be incorrect, and contrary to [most existing usage of the term on the site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=pubsub)).

Synonymising [pubsubhubbub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pubsubhubbub) with [websub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/websub), on the other hand, sounds to me like it makes sense (although the latter tag doesn't yet exist).

Comment: Rename followed by synonymisation?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 My inclination would be to retag some questions that use the term "WebSub" with [websub] and then synonymise, rather than to do a rename. It feels nicer to leave the [pubsubhubbub] tag visible on old questions from before "WebSub" was a thing, rather than change the tag on them anachronistically. But either way works.

Comment: Also, hubhub is the correct short name for PubSubHubBub

Comment: There was one question with [tag:websub] tag, and so I have synonymized [tag:pubsubhubbub] to it (had to do a swap, let's hope it works). I'm not much a fan of leaving it as synonyms and not merging them because it interferes with the badge tracking as well as searches. (I'll merge the tags this weekend if there's no opposition to it)